# Remove parameters from configure file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove some deprecated parameters on the same line in the configure file. For instant:

```
PARAM='param1=X param2=Y param3=Z param4=T opt1=A opt2=B'
```

The command  `sed -i 's/param.*//g' [file]`

will remove whole line instead of the expected ones ("param1,2,3 only").

Could you please give me some helps?

Thanks,
Hung

Comment: You want to keep the last `param` and the other `opt`s?

Comment: Yes, i just want to remove param* and keep opt. Moreover, i don't want to hardcode like sed -i 's/param1=X...

Comment: You want to remove **all** params? You mentioned in your question that you want to remove param1 , 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
cat test
PARAM='param1=X param2=Y param3=Z param4=T opt1=A opt2=B'
sed 's/param[1-3]=[^ ]*//ig' test
PARAM='   param4=T opt1=A opt2=B'
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Anyway, could you explain me more why using [^ ]* and "ig" (instead of g only)

Comment: Glad it worked!  'i' is for case insensitive. [^ ]* is to match all non space characters after the "=" sign (assuming the values are not constant across all params ).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sed`, the following might be helpful.

```
sed '/PARAM=/s/param[1-3]=[a-zA-Z] *//g'
```

or

```
sed '/PARAM=/s/param[1-3]=[^ ] *//g'
```

This does the following :

- If the line contains `PARAM=` (`/PARAM=/`)
- then replace the regex `param[1-3]=[a-zA-Z] *` by nothing (`s/param[1-3]=[a-zA-Z] *//g`)

The regex is build to match a single `param`

This outputs :

```
$ echo PARAM=\'param1=X param2=Y param3=Z param4=T opt1=A opt2=B\' \
  | sed '/PARAM=/s/param[1-3]=[a-zA-Z] *//g'
PARAM='param4=T opt1=A opt2=B'
```